# MICE for Boolean variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, imputation

I have a dataset with numerical and boolean values. But when I use MICE to impute the missing data, I get numerical values for missing boolean data. Here is my code

```
def do_MICE_imputation(train, test):
    import numpy as np
    min_value , max_value = {}, {}
    for col in train.columns:
        min_value[col] = np.min(train[col])
        max_value[col] = np.max(train[col])
        
    imp = IterativeImputer(random_state=0, min_value=list(min_value.values()),
                               max_value=list(max_value.values()), max_iter=5, verbose=10,
                               initial_strategy='most_frequent')
    imp.fit(train)
    train = pd.DataFrame(imp.transform(train), columns=train.columns)
    test = pd.DataFrame(imp.transform(test), columns=test.columns)
    return train, test
```

Initially, I was getting values greater than 1. To address that, I created the list of min and max values and passed that to MICE. But how do I ask MICE to create only 0 and 1 for Boolean variables?
Here is a snapshot of the result for Boolean variable called "[Pneumonia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7YEn.png)"

Comment: You might want to try [ai.se].

Comment: Thanks, I tagged it

Comment: This question probably belongs on the statistics site, https://stats.stackexchange.com. Its relation to AI is incidental.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way in sklearn to automatically detect if the data is binary or digital. You can use ColumnTransformer to treat your columns differently.